# How would I display my UI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm attempting to display my UI by calling the method from my clicker class to my main class.
Main class

```
package me.removed.clicker;

import me.removed.clicker.Clicker;

public class Main
{
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        Clicker.getClicker().openUI();
      }
    }
```

Clicker class

```
package me.removed.clicker;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl.Type;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import me.removed.clicker.handler.KeyboardHandler;
import me.removed.clicker.handler.MouseHandler;
import me.removed.clicker.util.Time;
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;

public class Clicker
{
  public static Clicker instance;
  private boolean LEFT_held;
  private boolean LEFT_skip;
  private Time LEFT_pressTime;
  private boolean toggled;
  private Random random;
  private ClickerFrame clickerFrame;
  private MouseHandler clickerHandler;
  private KeyboardHandler keyHandler;
  private Robot robot;
  private Thread thread;

  public boolean isToggled()
  {
    return this.toggled;
  }

  public void setToggled(boolean toggled)
  {
    this.toggled = toggled;
  }

  public Clicker()
  {
    this.LEFT_held = false;
    this.LEFT_skip = false;
    this.toggled = false;
    this.random = new Random();
    try
    {
      GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
      this.clickerHandler = new MouseHandler();
      this.keyHandler = new KeyboardHandler();
      GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseListener(this.clickerHandler);
      GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(this.keyHandler);
      this.robot = new Robot();
      LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
      Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen.class.getPackage().getName());
      logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        try
        {
          for (;;)
          {
            Thread.sleep(1L);
            if ((Clicker.this.isToggled()) && 


              (Clicker.this.isLeftHeld()))
            {
              long CPSDelay = Clicker.this.generateCPSDelay();
              if (Clicker.this.getLeftPressTime() != null)
              {
                if (Clicker.this.getLeftPressTime().hasPassed())
                {
                  Clicker.this.setLeftPressTime(new Time(CPSDelay));
                  Clicker.this.setLeftSkip(true);
                  Clicker.this.robot.mousePress(16);
                  Clicker.this.robot.mouseRelease(16);

                  Thread runThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
                  {
                    public void run()
                    {
                      try
                      {
                        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = 
                          AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Clicker.class.getClassLoader().getResource("left_click.wav"));

                        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

                        clip.open(audioInputStream);

                        float volume = -9.0F - Clicker.this.random.nextFloat() * 11.0F;


                        FloatControl gainControl = 
                          (FloatControl)clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
                        gainControl.setValue(volume);

                        clip.start();
                      }
                      catch (Exception localException) {}
                    }
                  });
                  runThread.start();
                }
              }
              else
              {
                Clicker.this.setLeftPressTime(new Time(CPSDelay));
                Clicker.this.setLeftSkip(true);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
    this.thread.start();
  }

  public boolean isLeftHeld()
  {
    return this.LEFT_held;
  }

  public void setLeftHeld(boolean LEFT_held)
  {
    this.LEFT_held = LEFT_held;
  }

  public void destroy()
  {
    try
    {

    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(0);
  }

  public void openUI()
  {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
      public void run()
      {
        try
        {
          UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo[] installedLookAndFeels;
          int length = (installedLookAndFeels = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()).length;
          for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
          {
            UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info = installedLookAndFeels[i];
            if ("Windows".equals(info.getName()))
            {
              UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
              break;
            }
          }
          Clicker.this.clickerFrame = new ClickerFrame();
          Clicker.this.clickerFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  public boolean getLeftSkip()
  {
    return this.LEFT_skip;
  }

  public void setLeftSkip(boolean LEFT_skip)
  {
    this.LEFT_skip = LEFT_skip;
  }

  public Time getLeftPressTime()
  {
    return this.LEFT_pressTime;
  }

  public void setLeftPressTime(Time LEFT_pressTime)
  {
    this.LEFT_pressTime = LEFT_pressTime;
  }

  public ClickerFrame getClickerFrame()
  {
    return this.clickerFrame;
  }

  public long generateCPSDelay()
  {
    int minCPS = 12;
    int maxCPS = 15;
    double minDiff = 83.0D;
    double maxDiff = 66.0D;
    double randomDiff = this.random.nextDouble() * 17.0D;
    return (long) (66.0D + randomDiff);
  }

  public static void setupClicker()
  {
    (Clicker.instance = new Clicker()).openUI();
  }

  public static Clicker getClicker()
  {
    return instance;
  }
}
```

You can see in my main class I attempted to call OpenUI however even when I do this nothing happens, the process runs but no UI opens, I tried removing Void also to no avail as shown in other posts.

CONSOLE ERRORS:

```
Jun 06, 2017 3:43:54 AM org.jnativehook.DefaultLibraryLocator getLibraries
INFO: Library extracted successfully: C:\Users\WarDev\AppData\Local\Temp\JNativeHook-2.0.3.dll (0x7432773EB4D09DC286D43FCC77DDB0E1E3BCE2B4).

Jun 06, 2017 3:43:54 AM java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary load
INFO: hook_get_auto_repeat_rate [42]: SPI_GETKEYBOARDSPEED: 31.

Jun 06, 2017 3:43:54 AM java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary load
INFO: hook_get_auto_repeat_delay [56]: SPI_GETKEYBOARDDELAY: 1.

Jun 06, 2017 3:43:54 AM java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary load
INFO: hook_get_pointer_acceleration_multiplier [70]: SPI_GETMOUSE[2]: 1.

Jun 06, 2017 3:43:54 AM java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary load
INFO: hook_get_pointer_acceleration_threshold [84]: SPI_GETMOUSE[0]: 6.

Jun 06, 2017 3:43:54 AM java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary load
INFO: hook_get_pointer_acceleration_threshold [86]: SPI_GETMOUSE[1]: 10.

Jun 06, 2017 3:43:55 AM java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary load
INFO: hook_get_pointer_sensitivity [101]: SPI_GETMOUSESPEED: 10.

Jun 06, 2017 3:43:55 AM java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary load
INFO: hook_get_multi_click_time [115]: GetDoubleClickTime: 500.

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at me.dewgs.clicker.ClickerFrame.<init>(ClickerFrame.java:442)
    at me.dewgs.clicker.Clicker$2.run(Clicker.java:175)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Where do you call `setUpClicker()`? If you don't call this, how will the Clicer instance be created? Proofread before posting please.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Clicker instance;
```

Looks to me like instance is null.

```
public static void setupClicker()
  {
    (Clicker.instance = new Clicker()).openUI();
  }
```

Where do you ever invoke `setupClicker()` to initialize the variable?

Why would you invoke `getClicker()` when you have the `setupClicker()` method to display the UI?

Comment: So I called the setupClicker() in main and yet nothing happens, same as before, task runs but no UI

Comment: @Ciaran, so did you add any debug code to see what is happening. Does the openUI() method get executed? Does the ClickerFrame get created. You need to do some basic debugging since you are using 3rd party classes. I see you use Thread.sleep(). Is that code executing on the `Event Dispatch Thread` which would prevent the GUI from painting itself.

Comment: I get quite the substantial amount of errors in console, updated to show console errors now

Comment: This is what my friend originally gave me, when you run it it runs perfectly fine however when I decompiled and attempted to recompile it with the src nothing works. www.mediafire.com/file/ha5d5zdy3er8a0e/math+lesson+12+bac.jar

Comment: `This is what my friend originally gave me,` - Well, talk to your friend. I no nothing about the custom classes. Again, debugging is part of programming. I suggest you learn how to do basic debugging to isolate the problem. The error messages tell you the line causing the problem, so figure out why you have a null variable.